# Which communication should I use between server and client

Tags: android, ios, performance, go, flutter

For a school project I am creating a multiplayer game for the smartphone. 
I want the "GUI" to be a flutter application to cover IOS and Android.
As backend I use Golang.

Now I wanted to ask, what is the best way that the backend and frontend can communicate together.
The communication should be fast and without a lot of calculations, because a lot of calculations are done by the backend, because I cannot allow cheating. And to have some performance it should be fast.

Comment: What have you tried based on your research so far? Where specifically are you stuck or encountering a bug/error?

Comment: Just copy-paste some example chat client and cannibalize that. That's how all school projects go